# PHP Session variables dissapear with header redirect

Tags: php, session

My session variables are empty when I login users and use a header redirect.

```
/* Login page */
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];

header("location:page.php");

/* page.php */

<?php echo $_SESSION[myusername]; ?>
```

Comment: session_register function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: u need to `session_start()` on every pages ! including the page on which you register the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use session_register function when you use $_SESSION superglobal array and you did not start your session. Try

```
/* Login page */
session_start();

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];

header("location:page.php");

/* page.php */

session_start();

<?php echo $_SESSION[myusername]; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `session_start();` in starting of the page..

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add  `session_start();` in top of the page

Answer (score 1):

add a

```
session_start()
```

as first!

Answer (score 1):

Did you include `session_start()` call at the start of the script page?,that is the most common issue i'm aware of with sessions in php.